# XTion does not match devices found on openni.launch

Tags: roslaunch, openni, xtion, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the ASUS Xtion pro on eletric Ubuntu 10.04. Long story short, it was working initially and then all my openni drivers got wiped, so reinstalled the drivers using the wiki.

Now when I try to run `rosrun openni_launch openni.launch` the device can be detected but says it is not a matching device as below. There is also no camera feed when using `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color`

```
[ INFO] [1412296948.638187940]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1412296948.640244380]: 1. device on bus 001:08 is a Xtion Pro (601) from ASUS (1d27) with serial id ''
[ INFO] [1412296948.645037848]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1412296952.665433343]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::OpenNIDevice(xn::Context&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-openni-kinect-0.3.6/debian/ros-electric-openni-kinect/opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp @ 99 : creating depth generator failed. Reason: Got a timeout while waiting for a network command to complete!
```

Does anyone know why this is occurring or what the error reason is?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194095/xtion-does-not-match-devices-found-on-openni.launch/) by [zemark](https://answers.ros.org/users/20369/zemark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Manged to solve my own problem. Followed this tutorial for Xtion Pro not being connected or matched and worked perfectly

http://robotica.unileon.es/mediawiki/index.php/PCL/OpenNI_troubleshooting#No_device_found_.2F_No_devices_connected

---

Originally posted by [zemark](https://answers.ros.org/users/20369/zemark/) with karma: 18 on 2014-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Couple of links for you to try

http://www.pcl-users.org/libusb-OpenNI-permission-denied-Kinect-amp-Ubuntu-td3720915.html

http://www.pcl-users.org/IOException-starting-up-openni-Grabber-td4025713.html

Cheers

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2014-10-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1